# Nginx not checking sites-enabled server blocks

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7

I've setup nginx and I am struggling with setting up my server blocks. I've created the sites-available and sites-enabled folder in /etc/nginx. Afterwards I created a file named as the subdomain I want to setup and put in the following contents:

**subdomain.mydomain.com (of course replaced with my real domain name)**

```
upstream subdomain.mydomain.com {
        server 127.0.0.1:1234;
        keepalive 30;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;

        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain.mydomain.com-error.log crit;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://subdomain.mydomain.com;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.mydomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
service nginx restart
```

Nginx restarted without issues, however the subdomain is not reachable. When I copy paste the above server block configuration into my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf http block it works completely fine.

**My question:**

Why it is not loading my server blocks from the sites-available folder? I guess this is the prefered way of adding new sites to nginx.

**Nginx.conf:**

https://ghostbin.com/paste/bfgqz

Comment: Can you post a copy of your nginx.conf too?

Comment: @Drifter104 sure, added a link to the config into the thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your distribution's nginx configuration does not read the `/etc/nginx/sides-enabled` directory at all, by default; you probably followed instruction for another distribution for the setup. The only place your nginx is looking for configuration files is `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, as determined by this line in your `nginx.conf`:

```
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Thus, you should either move configuration file to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/subdomain.mydomain.com.conf` (please note the `.conf` suffix), or change the nginx main configuration to also include the files in your sites-enabled folder  (*not recommended*, as your distribution's package manager might overwrite it during a future update).

Comment: Apparently that was the reason. I have never seen this approach before hence I even created the sites- folders

Comment: Here from the future to add that this answer helped fix my issue. I added `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` to `nginx.conf`.